# Concenating to every value in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, fwrite

So I have a file with some lines of text:

```
here's a sentence
look! another one
here's a third one too
and another one
one more
```

and I have some code that takes the each line and puts it into a list and then reverses the order of the whole list but now I don't know how to write each line back to the file and delete the existing ones in the text file.

Also when I run this code:

```
file_lines = open(file_name).readlines()
print(file_lines)
file_lines.reverse()
print(file_lines)
```

everything works and the line order is reversed, but when I run this code:

```
text_file = open(file_name, "w")
file_lines = open(file_name).readlines()
print(file_lines)
file_lines.reverse()
print(file_lines)
for line in file_lines:
    text_file.write(line)
```

it prints empty lists for some reason.

Comment: Show us how you create the `text_file` variable.

Comment: how did you open the `text_file`? use `open(filename, "w")`

Comment: Also can you please give us a sample of what's in `file_lines`?

Comment: Opening the file in `w+` mode erases the existing contents.

Comment: It prints empty list because you have used `\w+` mode which erases the content of file if it exists (otherwise it creates the file). So no more lines in the file and `[]` is on your screen. I have updated it in my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by doing just 2 little changes in your script.

1. Use `\r+` in place of `\w+`
2. Before performing write operation, place file position indicator to the beginning

   `text_file.seek(0)`

» `rw_file.txt` - before operation

```
here's a sentence
look! another one
here's a third one too
and another one
one more
```

Below is your modified script to reverse the content of file (It worked).

```
def reverseFile(file_name):
    text_file = open(file_name, "r+") # Do not use 'w+', it will erase your file content 
    file_lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in text_file.readlines()]
    file_lines.reverse()
    print(file_lines)

    text_file.seek(0) # Place file position indicator at beginning

    for line_item in file_lines:
        text_file.write(line_item+"\n")


reverseFile("rw_file.txt")
```

» `rw_file.txt` - after operation

```
one more
and another one
here's a third one too
look! another one
here's a sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open the file in `'w'` mode, the file is erased. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be
>   erased)

You should also use the `with` keyword:

> It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its
>   suite finishes...

I would recommend you *read* the contents of the file first, process that data, and then *write*:

```
def reverseFile(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        file_lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f.readlines()]
    file_lines.reverse()
    with open(file_name, "w") as f:
        for line in file_lines:
            f.write(line + '\n')

reverseFile('text_lines.txt')
```

Comment: This is the proper way of doing it. You can save a bunch of string copying by only stripping the first newline and appending only the last one. The ones in between take care of themselves.